# Gradle 7 and jitpack.io runs into error during publish

Tags: android, maven, gradle, publish, jitpack

When I upgrade in an Android project to Gradle 7.0 and want to publish aar library in jitpack.io I run into

```
Script '/script/maven-plugin.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
         > org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider
```

See full log https://jitpack.io/com/github/appdevnext/moka/0.7.1/build.log

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Maven plugin has been eliminated in Gradle 7.0, please use the maven-publish plugin instead.

I made it work with

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    // ...
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs 
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                artifact androidSourcesJar // optional sources
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you need an own `jitpack.yml`

```yaml
jdk:
  - openjdk11
install:
  - ./gradlew build :lib:publishToMavenLocal
```

Here you see complete pull request https://github.com/AppDevNext/Moka/pull/77 now it works https://jitpack.io/#AppDevNext/moka/1.0

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Have been search for 2 days on how to fix the Jitpack issue

Comment: Glad to help. I searched for days as well. Don't forget the question to up-vote ;-)

Comment: If I just copy the exact thing you posted and paste will it work?

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi Simply try it and after please rate it

Comment: Am sorry didnt work https://jitpack.io/com/github/MohammedAbidNafi/iOS-Style-Alert-Dialog/2.2/build.log

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi It works ! You simple have to fix other issues first https://github.com/MohammedAbidNafi/iOS-Style-Alert-Dialog/commit/61bece6858b796ed767578c3e2a1a398cb5d151b#r55615878

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi checkthis: https://github.com/MohammedAbidNafi/iOS-Style-Alert-Dialog/commit/61bece6858b796ed767578c3e2a1a398cb5d151b#commitcomment-57286369

Answer (score 1):

DSL version

```
    publishing {
      publications {
        val mavenJava by creating(MavenPublication::class) {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer from [hannes ach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079990/hannes-ach) worked for me.

With old gradle also a `...-sources.jar` file was uploaded to jitpack. To restore that behavior, the gradle snippet has to be slightly enhanced:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                artifact androidSourcesJar
            }
        }
    }
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ? I did a test drive https://jitpack.io/com/github/hannesa2/virocoreCommunity/rc-1.20.2/ and with sources https://jitpack.io/com/github/hannesa2/virocoreCommunity/rc-1.20.2-sources/ but content is the same

Comment: works here: https://jitpack.io/com/github/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/v3.4.3/ + https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/usbSerialForAndroid/build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I did these 3 steps (Called **jitpack**, Define **Java ver**. ,Publish **Maven**)
please follow them!

**1**- In `build.gradle(Project:...)` add:

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

then under `buildscript` part, add:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

**2**- In `build.gradle(Module:app)`, in `android` part add:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
```

**3**- In `build.gradle(Module:module-name)`, after `dependencies` part add:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.github.yourgitid' //your git id
                artifactId = 'Myket-Intent' //your-repository
                version = '0.1.15' // As same as the Tag
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me in Groovy

```
group = [groupId]
version = [version]

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    configurations.implementation.canBeResolved(true)
    configurations.api.canBeResolved(true)

    failOnError false

    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    //destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    classpath += configurations.api
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    archiveClassifier = "sources"
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

// Because the components are created only during the afterEvaluate phase, you must
// configure your publications using the afterEvaluate() lifecycle method.
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            // Creates a Maven publication called "release".
            release(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from components.release
                artifact(sourcesJar)

                // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
                groupId = 'com.github.[name].[repo]'
                artifactId = '[submodule name]'
                version = '[version]'

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = (asNode().get("dependencies") as groovy.util.NodeList).get(0) as groovy.util.Node
                    def configurationNames = ["implementation", "api"]

                    configurationNames.forEach { configurationName ->
                        configurations[configurationName].allDependencies.forEach {
                            if (it.group != null && it.version != "unspecified") {
                                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
                                dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                                dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                                dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
                                // dependencyNode.appendNode("scope", configurationName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following worked for me in KTS

```
group = [groupId]
version = [version]

val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    from(android.sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs)
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
}

val javadoc by tasks.registering(Javadoc::class) {
    configurations.implementation.get().isCanBeResolved = true
    configurations.api.get().isCanBeResolved = true

    isFailOnError = false
    source = android.sourceSets["main"].java.getSourceFiles()
    classpath += project.files(android.bootClasspath.joinToString(separator = File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.api
}

// build a jar with javadoc
val javadocJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    dependsOn(javadoc)
    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
    from(javadoc.get().destinationDir)
}

artifacts {
    archives(sourcesJar)
    archives(javadocJar)
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            register("mavenJava", MavenPublication::class) {
                groupId = "com.github.[name].[repo]"
                artifactId = "[submodule name]"
                version = "[version]"

                from(components["release"])
                artifact(sourcesJar.get())

                pom.withXml {
                    val dependenciesNode: groovy.util.Node =
                        (asNode().get("dependencies") as groovy.util.NodeList).get(0) as groovy.util.Node
                    val configurationNames = arrayOf("implementation", "api")

                    configurationNames.forEach { configurationName ->
                        configurations[configurationName].allDependencies.forEach {
                            if (it.group != null && it.version != "unspecified") {
                                val dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
                                dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                                dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                                dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
                                // dependencyNode.appendNode("scope", configurationName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beware that even with the `withXML` block, the transitive dependencies of `api` dependencies don't get added automatically. I had to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **known and documented** issue:

- Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'
- Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
- org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider

For my case I had to declare:

app/module/build.gradle

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.github.alkathirikhalid'
                artifactId = 'connection'
                version = 'v1.0.9'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and project/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

Reference:

- Code https://github.com/alkathirikhalid/connection/commit/e3195cae4e83eceaf430d7aa497088422e4b7ee3
- Ticket : https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/4772