# Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.MavenPomMetaInfoProvider'

Tags: android, android-studio

When I update gradle in android studio
I found this type error
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.MavenPomMetaInfoProvider'.
his is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599438/gradle-7-and-jitpack-io-runs-into-error-during-publish

Answer (score 31):

In my case, the issue was in this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

Before now, I was using Gradle plugin 4.2.2, and today I updated it to 7.0.0 and got the same error as you. I solved the issue by removing this line from my build.gradle.

Comment: after removing this i get: 
Could not find method install() for arguments [...] on project [...]

Comment: Downgrade your gradle version to 6.7.1. It works for me.

Comment: you will also need to remove this line from build.gradle if you have it.                           
            id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "2.0"   from plugins section

Comment: I don't have these lines at all, but like @Alex, I upgraded `gradle plugin version` to 7.0.1, 7.0.2... so on, and this error does not go away. My problem resolved on `gradle wrapper version` 6.7.1 and trying `gradle plugin version` 4.2.2 is final solution. @Satheesh, you can post your suggestion as answer, and I will upvote.

Comment: @mpountou you probably have an `install { }` block somewhere in a gradle file that you need to remove after upgrading to gradle 7+.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this issue when using a library pushed on jitpack.io
The docs on jitpack.io mention to include this in the root `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ....
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Where as with the latest updates this has changed. Android Studio no longer includes a allprojects block in the root `build.gradle` file.

To make this work you now need to include `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in `settings.gradle` file instead.

Here is how my settings.gradle looks like:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "<App Name>"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 3):

> DATE UPDATED EVERY TIME I GOT UPVOTE AS I KNOW IT IS STILL VALID

DATE: 04/11/2021 **(4th of Nov 2021)**

after receiving that error when updated to gradle 7.0.0, I tried @Alex solution but, it didn't work for me,

I removed two lines and it's working now.

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'
```

Comment: I don't have these lines at all, but like @Alex, I upgraded `gradle plugin version` to 7.0.1, 7.0.2... so on, and this error does not go away. My problem resolved on `gradle wrapper version` 6.7.1 and trying `gradle plugin version` 4.2.2 is final solution.

Answer (score 3):

Check if other modules have this plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

In my case it was in `countrycodepicker`

I removed it from there, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I migrate the project to the latest version in **July 2023**.

I was experience this issue in `countrycodepicker`.

In the file:

```
../../countrycodepicker/build.gradle
```

on line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

### Solution (Working in July 2023):

After removing the line, the component is now functioning properly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your gradle version to 6.7.1. It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Downgrading is never a correct answer. Downgrading leads to nothing. Some time in future you have to upgrade. What would you do?