# Android Jitpack ERROR: No build artifacts found

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

So am trying to publish my library in maven but this error is keep popping up I hope someone can help me with this. I have upgraded to java 11 even then this error is coming. Even though I upgraded to java 11 it still says java 1.8 please help with that too. I have even seen similar questions but those answers arent helping me.

If you need my projects link here it is https://github.com/MohammedAbidNafi/iOS-Style-Alert-Dialog

```
Git:
2.0.5-0-ga1f04f4
Found Android manifest
Android SDK version: 30. Build tools: 30.0.3
Installing Android platform 30
Installing Build-tools 30.0.3 
Found gradle
Gradle build script
Found gradle version: 7.0.2.
Using gradle wrapper
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
Unzipping /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0.2-bin/857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip to /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0.2-bin/857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r
Set executable permissions for: /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0.2-bin/857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r/gradle-7.0.2/bin/gradle

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e
Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Private Build 25.252-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.18.0-25-generic amd64

Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
0m3.308s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Tasks: 
WARNING:
Gradle 'install' task not found. Please add the 'maven' or 'android-maven' plugin.
See the documentation and examples: https://jitpack.io/docs/
Adding maven plugin
Found android library build file in iOSDialog
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.MohammedAbidNafi -Pversion=2.1 install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
> Configure project :
Gradle version Gradle 7.0.2
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 2
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
2021-08-23T17:06:45.866754989Z
Exit code: 0
ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811778/12272687