# maven-gradle-plugin is unavailable after andoird gradle upgrade to 7.0.0

Tags: android, maven, jitpack

Error message:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
         > org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider
```

Comment: got any answer?

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599438/gradle-7-and-jitpack-io-runs-into-error-during-publish