# android, after update to gradle 7, got error "Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'"

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-maven-plugin

The project has been working on Android studio 4.1.2 with gradle 6.8.3.
After update to Android studio 2021.2.1 and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```

and

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
```

and

```
     compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
     }
 
     kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
     }
```

Now it failed to sync:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
```

Searched and [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599438/gradle-7-and-jitpack-io-runs-into-error-during-publish) do not work for me.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

[image]